HandleError in React
how to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.4.168/pdf.worker.min.js     at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:284680:58)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:284699:7"

The link appears to be incorrect. Analyzing the source I found the following:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.worker.min.js
Apparently, the correct way to access is to use https, instead of http.
